# Why is the well-ordering theorem so important in the set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, well-orders

Why is the well-ordering theorem so important in the set theory?

> Every set can be well-ordered.

Mathematicians think the above theorem is very important but the below theorem is not so important.
Of course I know that the above theorem is stronger than the below theorem.
But why is the above theorem so important?

> Every set can be totally-ordered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most simply, well-orderings let us do things that arbitrary total orders don't - namely, they support **definition by (transfinite) recursion** and **proof by (transfinite) induction**.

The difference is most clearly seen if we look at "constructions" of weird sets of reals: $\mathsf{ZF}$ obviously proves that $\mathbb{R}$ can be totally ordered, but a mere total ordering of $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't help us build a Vitali set, a Bernstein set, an undetermined game on the naturals, or etc. - for any of those, we need a *well-ordering*.

Comment: Noah Schweber, Thank you very much for your answer.